Classic view display whereas modern experience selected in a list
i got a list which have a calendar view. I use the advanced parameter so that this list will be used in modern experience.

When i am on the same list using a calendar view i created it opens the panel/form in modern experience  Whereas when i put a webpart on a page using this list with the same calendar view and that i click on a cell to add an item it opens in classic view through list/Alist/newform.aspx  
What can i do so that the panel/form (modern experience) will open even when using the webpart and clicking on the calendar? I don't want the classic view  and i dont understand why the classic view appear.

I tested it and when I added a new item, a new page opened, and the form was displayed in the modern experience. Maybe your site page Library is in classic experience, or your form has special columns?

thanks @KarleyZhou-MSFT . what do you mean by special columns?
